# Having difficulties converting bs3 input group to bs4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I had an input group with two inputs and a prepended text, by default in bs3 the two inputs were placed on top of each other, and the prepended text's height was stretched for these inputs automatically.

Now i switched to bs4 and now the inputs are aligned side by side, and because of the flex display, i dont know how to make them vertically positioned.

This is how i want it to displayed:

```
_________________________________________________
|              |     input 1                     |
|prepended text|_________________________________
|              |     input 2                     |
_________________________________________________
```

This is how it looks now with bs4:

```
______________________________________________________
|prepended text  |     input 1 |    input 2          |
______________________________________________________
```

sorry for this presentation

If i override the width of inputs, or try to make them blocks, the prepeded text wont strech into two rows.

```
<div class="col-12">
 <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
   <span class="input-group-text">text</span>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never mind, i just figured out a simple solution, by just wrapping the inputs inside a div

Comment: are deleting this or answering your own question?